# Extensionless SEO Friendly with Asp.net webforms

Tags: asp.net, url-rewriting, url-routing

How to get extension less and without query string  SEO friendly  URL for asp.net web forms.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found out a very good article [Here](http://intelliwins.com/blog/post/Seo-Friendly-URL-Redirection-On-Aspnet-Web-Forms)

It is a very good blog post written on how to redirect urls which contain query strings as extension less seo friendly urls.

One method of doing it by including Global.asax into the application.

Here is the example.

Include Global.asax into the application.

```
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Web.Routing" %>
```

inside global.asax file

```
void registerroute(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.MapPageRoute(
            "Home-Route",
            "Home",
            "~/Default.aspx"
            );
}
```

Which will map the home page or default page

For Query string urls like http://xyz.com/page.aspx?id=about

```
routes.MapPageRoute(
          "Page-Route",
          "Pages/{page}",
          "~/page.aspx"
          );
```

Then call this registerroute() inside application start event under Global.asax

```
 void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
        // Code that runs on application startup
        registerroute(RouteTable.Routes);
    }
```

Then to access the query string inside pages.

```
string pg = Page.RouteData.Values["page"] as string;
```

Comment: The link may theoretically answer the question, but [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Agreed with @Juhana. You need to provide a snipped of code extracted from the website to help other developers understand what to look for. Maybe even include that they are looking at URL Routing.